# SwiftUI Form Cell losing selection UI when drilling into details?

Tags: ios, swiftui, navigationview

I have the following code:

```
enum SelectedDetails:Int, CaseIterable {
    case d0
    case d1
}


struct CellSelectionTestView : View {
    
    @State var selection:SelectedDetails? = .d0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            Form {
                
                Section(header: Text("Section 0")) {
                    NavigationLink(destination: D0DetailsView(),
                                   tag: .d0,
                                   selection: $selection) {
                        D0CellView().frame(height: 80)
                    }
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: D1CellView(),
                                   tag: .d1,
                                   selection: $selection) {
                        D1CellView().frame(height: 80)
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}


struct D0CellView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("D0")
    }
    
}

struct D0DetailsView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(0..<10) { n in
                    NavigationLink.init(destination: OptionsDetailsView(index:n)) {
                        Text("show \(n) details")
                    }
                }
            }
            .refreshable {
                
            }
        }
    }
    
}

struct OptionsDetailsView: View {
    
    let index:Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("OptionsDetailsView \(index)")
    }
    
}




struct D1CellView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("D1")
    }
    
}
```

When I tap on `D0` cell, it shows this:

[image]

**`D0` cell correctly shows the selected state UI.**

Then I tap on one of the `show <n> details` cells and the selection goes away:
[image]

How do I keep `D0` cell selected UI stated active until I tap on another cell like `D1` for example regardless of what I do in the details view to the right? I need to keep UI context as the user does what is needed within the details shown when `D0` is tapped. Why is that selection going away if I didn't even tap on `D1`?

Answer (score 0):

Strange, but it seems like `NavigationView` can only keep one selection. I found a workaround by integrating a second `NavigationView` with .stacked style in your child view:

```
struct D0DetailsView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(0..<10) { n in
                        NavigationLink {
                            OptionsDetailsView(index:n)
                        } label: {
                            Text("show \(n) details")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .refreshable {
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
}
```

Comment: that indeed does keep the selection, but unfortunately adds navigation UI on the right, so the it shows the normal navigation and another one inside it. Can't use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: save the last active selection and set the select background color manually:

```
struct CellSelectionTestView : View {
    
    @State private var selection: SelectedDetails? = .d0
    @State private var selectionSaved: SelectedDetails = .d0

    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Section 0")) {
                    NavigationLink(tag: .d0, selection: $selection) {
                        D0DetailsView()
                    } label: {
                        D0CellView().frame(height: 80)
                    }
                    .listRowBackground(selectionSaved == .d0 ? Color.gray : Color.clear)
                    
                    NavigationLink(tag: .d1, selection: $selection) {
                        D1CellView()
                    } label:{
                        D1CellView().frame(height: 80)
                    }
                    .listRowBackground(selectionSaved == .d1 ? Color.gray : Color.clear)
                }
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: selection) { newValue in
            if selection != nil { selectionSaved = selection! }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: here https://lostmoa.com/blog/ProgrammaticNavigationInSwiftUIListView/ is another solution.